# Pandas Series partial Replacement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a state column in pandas dataframe like this:
This is sample data. Actual may differ.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"state": ["Uttar Pradesh", "Jammu & Kashmir", "Jammu&Kashmir", "Puducherry"]})
```

Now task is to change `Jammu & Kashmir` to `Jammu and Kashmir` and `Puducherry` to `Pondicherry`

So I create a dictionary for this

```
STATE_MAP_DICT = {
    "jammu&kashmir": "Jammu and Kashmir",
    "orissa": "Odisha",
    "orrissa": "Odisha",
    "puducherry": "pondicherry",
    "damananddiu": "Dadra and Nagar Haveli"
}
```

then

```
df['state'] = df["state"].astype(str).str.replace(' ','').str.lower().replace(STATE_MAP_DICT)
```

Expectation :

```
["Uttar Pradesh", "Jammu and Kashmir", "Jammu and Kashmir", "pondicherry"]
```

Output :

`["uttarpradesh", "Jammu and Kashmir", "Jammu and Kashmir", "pondicherry"]  # Uttar Pradesh`

Changed since i used replace() and lower()

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html?highlight=fillna#pandas.Series.fillna) methods.

```
df["state"] = df["state"].astype(str).str.replace(' ','').str.lower().map(STATE_MAP_DICT).fillna(df["state"])
```

Output:

```
    state
0   Uttar Pradesh
1   Jammu and Kashmir
2   Jammu and Kashmir
3   pondicherry
```

Comment: This is not the required part. Please check my expected output.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I just update the answer, please checking again. Btw I test with this another dataframe and work as expected: `df = pd.DataFrame({"state": ["Uttar Pradesh", "Jammu & Kashmir", "Uttar Pradesh 2", "Jammu&Kashmir", "Puducherry"]})`

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following entries to your dictionary:

```py
{
  'pondicherry': 'Pondicherry',
  'uttarpradesh' 'Uttar Pradesh'
}
```

Alternatively, use a custom function instead of `str`:

```py
def f(s):
  s2= s.replace(' ', '').lower()
  if s2 in STATE_MAP_DICT:
    return STATE_MAP_DICT[s2]
  return s

df['state'] = df["state"].apply(f)
```

Comment: This is not good then I have to maintain each possibility in the dictionary. But it is known to me only few state names have this problem. Are you getting my point.

Comment: The second option does not require you to have every state covered. It handles this problem specifically: for every state that isn't present in the dictionary it will take `s` rather than the lowercases stripped version. Try it :)

Comment: I missed that. Yes got it. But as a advise remove that dictionary part else your answer is good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.where` and check if value exists in dictionary keys after replacement and making strings lower. If so, we wanna replace it, if not - we leave it without changes:

```
import numpy as np

val = df["state"].str.replace(' ','').str.lower()

df['state'] = np.where(val.isin(STATE_MAP_DICT.keys()),
                       val.replace(STATE_MAP_DICT),
                       df['state']
                       )
```

Output:

```
                state
0       Uttar Pradesh
1   Jammu and Kashmir
2   Jammu and Kashmir
3         pondicherry
```

Comment: Yes I tried it but waiting for some better approach. This will work fine. I felt there is any option for partial replacement in pandas. If not found one then I would accept this answer for sure.